# io_context concurrency hint (BOOST_ASIO_CONCURRENCY_HINT_UNSAFE_IO)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

While checkig the documentation of boost::asio in verion 1.66.0, I noticed that the io_context constructor provides a [`concurrency_hint`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/concurrency_hint.html) parameter. After reading the documentation, I'm unsure if I can use `BOOST_ASIO_CONCURRENCY_HINT_UNSAFE_IO`.

I have following situation:

- I have a single `io_context` to do the IO. `ioc.run()` is executed from a single thread.
- In this thread, some network IO using async calls are executed.
- Other threads call `boost::asio::dispatch(ioc, ...)` to execute code on the IO thread.

I'm trying to figure out what [concurrency hint](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/concurrency_hint.html) value is safe to use in the situation as described  above:

- Using no concurrency hint is ok (eg. `BOOST_ASIO_CONCURRENCY_HINT_SAFE`), but slower than with hints.
- Using `1` is ok.
- Using `BOOST_ASIO_CONCURRENCY_HINT_UNSAFE` is not ok because it doesn't allow async calls.

What is unclear to me is `BOOST_ASIO_CONCURRENCY_HINT_UNSAFE_IO`. Documentation says:

> This special concurrency hint disables locking in the reactor I/O. This hint has the following restrictions:
>
> — Care must be taken to ensure that run functions on the io_context, and all operations on the context's associated I/O objects (such as sockets and timers), occur in only one thread at a time.

I wonder if it's safe do a `boost::asio::dispatch` from another thread when using this concurrency hint.

Answer (score 1):

Since `boost::asio::dispatch`¹ [ends up calling `io_context::dispatch`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/dispatch/overload2.html) I would conclude that it's *not ok* to use `BOOST_ASIO_CONCURRENCY_HINT_UNSAFE_IO` if you call it from another thread:

> — Care must be taken to ensure that run functions on the io_context, and all operations on the context's associated I/O objects (such as sockets and timers), occur in only one thread at a time.

---

¹ same for post/defer

Comment: I agree that `BOOST_ASIO_CONCURRENCY_HINT_UNSAFE` cannot be used in this context. However, what about `BOOST_ASIO_CONCURRENCY_HINT_UNSAFE_IO`? In this mode some locking is done, and I consider the documentation unclear whether a dispatch is allowed.

Comment: Oops. I mean to say `BOOST_ASIO_CONCURRENCY_HINT_UNSAFE_IO`.  Fixed